# Connecting to multiple databases in mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I have a web application where I have to use multiple dbs (static set of dbs) in mongodb. For a given request, the db depends on few parameters passed as part of request. I use `spring framework's mongoTemplate` for interacting with the DB. There are 2 ways in which I can get `MongoTemplate` instance for a particular DB.

1. By using just `Mongo` instance which will be initialized as part of web application context. Using this, I can get `MongoTemplate` for a given DB.
2. Using a `MongoDBFactory`

In the first method,

```
@Autowired
private Mongo mongo;

MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate(String dbName) {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongo, dbName);
}
```

Second method,

```
@Autowired
private MongoDbFactory factory;

MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate(String dbName) {
    DB db = factory.getDb(dbName);
    Mongo mongo = db.getMongo();
    return new MongoTemplate(mongo);
}
```

Which of these 2 is ideal?

Answer (score 0):

If I got your requirement correct, You want to connect two mongo dbs. In that case, it will not be possible to have one MongoTemplate instance creation logic and use to create two mongo db connections. I feel you got to have two simillar logic with @Qualifier on top of it.

First Config Class

```
@Autowired
@Bean(name="mongoDbFactory1")
private MongoDbFactory factory;

@Bean(name="mongoTemplate1")
MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate(String dbName) {
    DB db = factory.getDb(dbName);
    Mongo mongo = db.getMongo();
    return new MongoTemplate(mongo);
}
```

Another Config Class

```
@Autowired
@Bean(name="mongoDbFactory2")
private MongoDbFactory factory;

@Bean(name="mongoTemplate2")
MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate(String dbName) {
    DB db = factory.getDb(dbName);
    Mongo mongo = db.getMongo();
    return new MongoTemplate(mongo);
}
```

Class where you want to perform operations on Collection using mongoTemplate.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("mongoTemplate2")
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

Again if your question is whether either of the mentioned logic work then both will properly assuming you have Mongo or MongoFactory creation logic available somewhere in your code (which you are trying to Autowire in resepective methods)

Comment: you're basically creating a mongoTemplate for each db. But there might be a use case tomorrow where in a new DB needs to be created. In that case, I'll end up changing code to create the respective factory and template which I dont want to do.

Comment: Ok. I doubt if we can create spring beans with same name and type on fly that would have its own intelligence to understand that it is being created for which DB. Default srping beans are singleton and to avoid confusion among multiple beans we have Bean name or qualifier as an identifier. In that case my be a Prototype kind bean will be useful. But again I guess Prototype would return a clone of an instance.